# Tomcat HttpServletResponse NIO Support

Tags: java, tomcat, nio

I'm running my API server with Tomcat 8.5 (Spring boot embedded). There's 1 API that needs to read an image file from the server's file system and then return it. Since the API will be in heavy use, I'd like to explore ways to improve its performance. I wonder if I can directly send the file to response without copying it inside JVM. The NIO package seems to be the choice here but I'm not sure if the Tomcat HttpServletResponse supports it.

The `Channels.newChannel(response.getOutputStream())` only seems to return a wrapper.

In general, I'm not sure if the following implementation is using NIO (direct kernel space copy) or just traditional IO underneath.

```
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        try (FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(path);
             ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {

            long size = fileChannel.size();
            int position = 0;
            WritableByteChannel outChannel = Channels.newChannel(outputStream);
            while (position < size) {
                position += fileChannel.transferTo(position, size, outChannel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This article drom DZone may help you: [
The Processing of Data](https://dzone.com/articles/java-nio-vs-io)

Comment: Thank you for sharing it, but it doesn't really help with my question.

Comment: Have a look at the [Advanced IO and Tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/aio.html). I don't have any example, maybe can you write one and post your own anwer, it would be great.